# While I want to use the data members from .h file to the other file

Tags: c++

I am using the two .h files and the two .cpp file.

The employee.h file contains

```
class Employee
{
        public:
          std::string Name,Id,Address;
};
```

The second .h file stack.h contains

```
 #include "employee.h"
class Stack
{
  public:
   int total=0;
    void push();
    void pop();
    void display();
};
```

The first.cpp file stack.cpp contains

```
#include "stack.h"

Employee obj1;
Stack emp[10];
void Stack::push()
{
  if(total>=10)
  {
    total--;
    std::cout <<"Stack is Overflowed";
  }
  else
  {
   std::cout<<"Enter data of employee "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Enter employee name: ";
   std::cin>>emp[total].obj1.Name;
    std::cout<<"Enter id: ";
    std::cin>>emp[total].obj1.Id;
    std::cout<<"Enter address: ";
    std::cin>>emp[total].obj1.Address;
  }
  total++;
}
```

The second cpp file main.cpp contains

```
#include "stack.h"
Stack obj;
int main()
{
  obj.push();
}
```

While i am executing above files it is giving an error like this

```
g++ stack.cpp main.cpp
stack.cpp: In member function ‘void Stack::push()’:
stack.cpp:16:25: error: ‘class Stack’ has no member named ‘obj1’
    std::cin>>emp[total].obj1.Name;
                         ^~~~
stack.cpp:18:26: error: ‘class Stack’ has no member named ‘obj1’
     std::cin>>emp[total].obj1.Id;
                          ^~~~
stack.cpp:20:26: error: ‘class Stack’ has no member named ‘obj1’
     std::cin>>emp[total].obj1.Address;
```

If i remove the obj1 from stack.cpp then it will giving an error like this
code:

```
std::cout<<"Enter data of employee "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Enter employee name: ";
   std::cin>>emp[total].Name;
    std::cout<<"Enter id: ";
    std::cin>>emp[total].Id;
    std::cout<<"Enter address: ";
    std::cin>>emp[total].Address;
```

Error:

```
g++ stack.cpp main.cpp
stack.cpp: In member function ‘void Stack::push()’:
stack.cpp:16:25: error: ‘class Stack’ has no member named ‘Name’
    std::cin>>emp[total].Name;
                         ^~~~
stack.cpp:18:26: error: ‘class Stack’ has no member named ‘Id’
     std::cin>>emp[total].Id;
                          ^~
stack.cpp:20:26: error: ‘class Stack’ has no member named ‘Address’
     std::cin>>emp[total].Address;
```

Can anyone please help to this problem?

Comment: `emp` is an array of `Stack` and the error clearly says that `Stack` does not have member named `Name` and `obj1`. What isn't clear from that? The program doesn't even make sense. Refer to a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `Stack emp[10];` gives you 10 stacks, not 10 employees.

Comment: `emp[total]` refers to a `Stack` object not an `Employee` object.

Comment: If i change my code like Employee emp[10] instead of Stack emp[10] in stack.cpp. is it resolve my error.

Comment: @pottirohith Put `Employee emp[10];` **inside** `class Stack { ... };` That is the way to resolve the error.

Comment: But if you change your code like that, then `stack` is no longer needed. Not only that, ctually, using an array here at all defeats the whole purpose of having a stack.

Comment: @Spencer Well it's true you would not code a stack like this for real, but this is a learning exercise.

Comment: @john Yes, that's  OK inside the implementation of `stack`. But the change OP made appears to have been at global scope.

Comment: @Spencer OK, fair enough, I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are trying to create  stack of employees. The way to do this is to put the employees **inside** the Stack. Like this

```
class Employee
{
public:
    std::string Name,Id,Address;
};

class Stack
{
public:
    int total=0;
    Employee emp[10]; // 10 employees
    void push();
    void pop();
    void display();
};

void Stack::push()
{
    std::cout<<"Enter data of employee "<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Enter employee name: ";
    std::cin>>emp[total].Name;
    std::cout<<"Enter id: ";
    std::cin>>emp[total].Id;
    std::cout<<"Enter address: ";
    std::cin>>emp[total].Address;
}
```

You already did this right with `total`, it's just the same for everything else that you want to be part of a `Stack`.

Comment: I need to create a stack of employees only but i have to made it like one .h file for employee class and one .h file for stack class and .cpp file for declaring methods in stack.h and finally i have to execute it in the one more main.cpp file. like this i have to do so that's why i have posted the question.

Comment: @pottirohith OK, but you still have to do it like I said above. Why does the code above not work for you?

Comment: @pottirohith Just put `#include "Employee.h"` at the top of `Stack.h`.  But then declare `Stack` just the way John described.

Comment: Additional recommendation: `push` does too much. All a function named `push` should do is push an object onto the stack. All of the user input should be elsewhere, perhaps an `operator >>` overload for `Employee`. In general a function should do one thing (and do it well) that way you have a bunch of small, easy to test, and reusable building blocks that you can build more complicated programs around.

Comment: @user4581301  You're right; prompting for each employee's details is a job for some UX function (in this case `main`).